# why token burn send token to an address

Tags: solidity, erc-20

In all the erc20 contracts, the burn method transfers tokens to address 0 and not actually deletes the number. Making the tokens appear in the circulating supply. Why not just delete them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There many different implementations of a contract adhering to the IERC20 interface. OpenZeppelin's ERC20 implementation does change the `_totalSupply` via the `_burn` method

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.1.0/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol#L263

Comment: yes, but why do they transfer the tokens to address 0?

Comment: Because it's considered as the burn address by most people. As to why it's chosen as the burn address - well there are probably a few reasons. 1) It's easy to remember 2) It's probably more gas efficient using zeroes for certain operations

Comment: why do you even need a burn address? why not just delete them

Comment: You could :) This is just OpeZeppelin's implementation however. I assume they do this because they are reusing functions/events like `transfer`/`Transfer`